# Ruby : Group a Hash with an occurrence restriction (?)

Tags: ruby, group-by

Given an array of objects exampled below.

```rb
[
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '2' },
  { group: '1' }
]
```

Expected output would be:

```rb
[
  [{ group: '1' }, { group: '1' }, { group: '1' }],
  [{ group: '2' }],
  [{ group: '1' }]
]
```

Important to note that even though "group 1" occurs 4 times, there will be 2 different groupings because we're taking the position of the object in the array as well... the group names are arbitrary as well.

Comment: For it to be an array of hashes there must be a comma after every hash but the last. While you're at it, please assign a variable to the array (e.g., `arr = [....]`) so that readers can refer to the array without having to define it. Also the commas within the hashes cause no harm but there's no reason for them to be there. Lastly, `[{ group: '1', }, { group: '1', } { group: '1', }],` is missing a comma.

Comment: @CarySwoveland fixed, but this isn't meant to be copy pasted as actual code. Looking for methods to solving this type of problem. I don't _actually_ need to group this set at all -- I seek the functionality that I'm describing (which I've found with Enumerable#chunk in the accepted answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does this with a builtin: [Chunk](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)

> Enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return value of the block.
>
> Consecutive elements which return the same block value are chunked together.

Which looks like exactly what you want:

```rb
data
  .chunk{ |item| item[:group] }
  .map{ |_chunk_value, items| items } # chunk gives a pair of the value the chunk used and the values in the chunk, but we only need the values.
```

Comment: TIL: `Chunk` -- VERY clean! I ended up hacking with an array being built, I'm refactoring to chunk now.

Comment: You can simplify to `arr.chunk(&:itself).map(&:last)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that is fine :) I'm not really after solving this code block, but rather the functionality Chunk provides -- which is perfect

Comment: Vipa, keep in mind that answers and comments are intended to have educational value for readers generally, beyond whatever help they may be to you.

Comment: Enumerable has a lot of very useful stuff. I always check the docs there.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '1' },
  { group: '2' },
  { group: '1' }
]
```

```
arr.slice_when { |g,h| g[:group] != h[:group] }.to_a
  #=> [[{:group=>"1"}, {:group=>"1"}, {:group=>"1"}],
  #    [{:group=>"2"}], 
  #    [{:group=>"1"}]]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

Comment: well done, #slice_when is another great solution -- I'll have to benchmark them to see which would perform better in code

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `results = []` and then build it up by iterating over the input. As you process each input hash, you check whether the last element in `results` matches. If so, you add the input hash there. Otherwise, you start a new list in `results`:

```
input = [
  { group: '1', },
  { group: '1', },
  { group: '1', },
  { group: '2', },
  { group: '1', }
]

results = []
input.each do |hsh|
  last = results.last
  if last && last.last[:group] == hsh[:group]
    last.push hsh
  else
    results.push [hsh]
  end
end

print results
# => [
#      [{:group=>"1"}, {:group=>"1"}, {:group=>"1"}],
#      [{:group=>"2"}],
#      [{:group=>"1"}]
#    ]
```

Comment: this is actually what I ended up with shortly after posting this question. However, the winner is going to be `Chunk` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk